# PayPal API to get tax detail configured in PayPal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm looking for an API to get international sales tax configured in PayPal.

Our client configured international sales tax varies from country to country in PayPal: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/admin/checkout-settings/#access-your-sales-tax-rates-in-your-account-profile

We need to get sales tax configured in PayPal via API so that we can show tax in our web application cart page based on user country set in profile

Does PayPal have API exposed to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Tax and shipping configured in the PayPal account is only for old HTML/link-only PayPal integrations from ~20 years ago, which predate the existence of APIs. It is not intended to be used, and will not work with, any newer PayPal integration.

Current PayPal integrations which calculate tax/shipping outside of PayPal must manage their own tax/shipping configuration, and specify the amounts when sending the transaction to PayPal.

Comment: Thanks for the information. We would conclude same . Do we have any PayPal forum link confirming same so that it would help us to share as proof of information

Comment: It's only for the old HTML version of PayPal Payments Standard. You can find documentation on it here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#calculate-sales-tax-automatically

Comment: PayPal payment buttons as described there are the simple ones at https://www.paypal.com/buttons